# A proxy forward to redirect some calls to avoid crossing the proxy. Only redirect proxy forward

Tags: nginx, squid, varnish

I'm trying to redirect with 301 some https calls with some proxy forward. The idea is not to go through the proxy, but to return a 301 redirect with the new location. I've got two cases:

```
https://example.com/dummy/copy/this/path -> https://another.com/other/copy/this/path
```

So when I call a curl

```
https_proxy=myforwardproxy:8080 curl https://example.com/dummy/copy/this/path
```

It should return a redirection 301 to https://another.com/other/copy/this/path with the Host changes and the path reused (avoiding dummy parent path)

I'll try with **Nginx**, **Squid**, **Varnish**, and **skipper** with the same result.
This is the real thing that I want to do:
[image: network diagram]

Which program will should use? I see that the only can do a redirect proxy forward is **Squid**, but it uses [Redirection Programs](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Redirectors) (perl scripts or deprecated solutions).

Also I tried NGINX, but need an upstream and I can't configure to avoid crossing the proxy and alwys return 400 Bad Request.

And with varnish I cant get a real Probe of Concept.

Comment: maybe stop looking for the keyword "proxy". This server is not a proxy. It's just a normal server.

Comment: Hello @user253751. The word is totally correct. It is a proxy because it is a middle element that intercept calls to outside, and in this case, redirect or forward to another destination. Also is correct use proxy, because I want to use with env vars HTTPS_PROXY and HTTP_PROXY. So, it's a proxy

Comment: How does curl know *not* to use the proxy the second time?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Squid, Varnish is a reverse caching proxy. Its role is to cache content from the origin server and is hosted on the edge. The DNS record for `example.com` should be pointed to the Varnish server.

If that's not the case and you're just using the proxy locally, you're looking for a forward proxy like Squid.